# REST API call works from terminal with curl but I get 404 in browser from my Vue / axios app

Tags: rest, vue.js, express

If do curl like this:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:3600/users \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'user-agent: vscode-restclient' \
  --data '{"email": "marcos.henrique@toptal.com","password": "sup3rS3cr3tPassw0rd!23"}'
```

This returns as expected:

```
{"id":"6077f1853bd1e07f173980ef"}
```

But in my Vue code:

```
      const axios = require("axios");
      console.log("Here goes nothing!");

      let res = axios
        .post(
          "/http://localhost:3600/users", //
          {
            email: "marcos.henrique@toptal.com",
            password: "sup3rS3cr3tPassw0rd!23",
          }
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

in browsers it shows in console returns:

```
{"message":"Request failed with status code 404","name":"Error","stack":"createError\nsettle\nhandleLoad","config":{"url":"/http://localhost:3600/users","method":"post","data":"{\"email\":\"marcos.henrique@toptal.com\",\"password\":\"sup3rS3cr3tPassw0rd!23\"}","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1}}
```

To me it looks like the axios request was correct but something else went wrong.

I suspected CORS problem and tried to disable it in Safari (I'm on macOS) with Develop/Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions and Develop Disable Local File Restrictions.

I get the same error in Chrome where I have also tried to disable CORSs.

Before disabling I got some CORS exceptions but now I get 404.

My REST API is from this blog / demo:

[https://www.toptal.com/express-js/nodejs-typescript-rest-api-pt-2]

and this code repo:

[https://github.com/makinhs/toptal-rest-series]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `/` from first in this line

```js
"/http://localhost:3600/users"
```

Comment: Thanks! How embarrassing, well spotted. I've had umpteen different versions of this code today with various formats of the URL with IP and localhost, with http:// and without etc etc and of course when all the other ducks are in the row then I make silly typo like that.

Works now, thanks again.

Comment: Have been there many times before ;) You never expect the simplest solution.